# Access parent controller attribute from Visual force component

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, visualforce-component, salesforcedx-cli

I have one Visualforce page and one Visualforce controller. I have different attributes defined in the controller of Visualforce page as shown below

```
 public boolean firstPanel{get;set;}
 public boolean secondPanel{get;set;}
 public boolean thirdPanel{get;set;}
```

I also have a separate controller for Visualforce component which is being called inside in visualforce page and i am passing certain list of object in visualforce component from visualforce page.
I have a function in the controller of Visualforce component which is being called when certain sets of operation is required.

Now i want when these operations are being called then attributes(firstPanel,secondPanel,thirdPanel) defined in the parent controller should be set in the component controller without redirecting. How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to pass a reference of the page controller into the component like this.

The component has an attribute defined:

```
<apex:component controller="ComponentController">
    <apex:attribute name="pc" type="PageController" description=""/>
    ...
</apex>
```

The page sets a value in that attribute via a controller property:

```
<c:component pc="{!controller}" .../>
```

The page controller property is this:

```
public PageController controller {
    get {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then your component markup can reference the page controller properties via `{pc}`. For example `{!pc.firstPanel}`.

Comment: How can i set the value of firstPanel which is the attribute of pagecontroller in component controller in APEX Class?

Comment: @Sheheri My bad I misunderstood your question. I don't have an answer to that.

Comment: @KeithC, found a post of yours addressing similar problem : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220858/pass-controller-variable-value-to-another-controller-class  .@Sheheri check this

Comment: @Arabinda i dont have controller extensions in my solution. I only have one visualforce page and two visualforce component and 3 apex controllers for each visualforce page and visualforce controller. Visualforce components are included in Visualforce page. There are some logic performed on each visualforce component on the basis of which i need to decide, if i have to show the other visualforce component or not.To show the other component boolean variable has been declared in controller of Visualforce page but i dont have any way on how to access that from componenet controller.

Comment: @MuhammadSheheryarAfsar, that case I can suggest you to use cookies to store some temp variables and manipulate based on your requirement.
Give a try for this cookies approach. As in your case, extensions are not linked so this approach can help.